# x axis Error when plotting with dotplot (binaxis = "y") - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Can you please help me understand why my x axis look weird and help me resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were thinking about using geom_point instead of geom_dotplot ? Your axis is discrete because you used  a factor variable but indeed you have a blank space on the right.
Maybe you could instead of using two dataset, doing the ggplot on one and using the color variable you created to color the right points.

```
   storeProfit = storeProfit %>%mutate(color = (min(totalProfit) == totalProfit | max(totalProfit) == totalProfit))
  

ggplot(data = storeProfit, aes(x = factor(STORE), y = totalProfit,fill=color)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", fill = "light blue")+
  labs(title = "Total softdrink profit per Store", x = "Store", y = "Total Profit (USD$)") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
scale_fill_manual(c("light blue","red"))
```

This is the best I can think without a reproducible dataset

Comment: Note that this kind of data maybe be suited to barplot. You can find all possibilities of visualizations well explained on the GGplot2 cheatsheet available on internet